# Restaurar Backup .bak en sql 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, firestore

hola a todos estoy tratando de recuperar un backup de un sistema, tengo el archivo .bak y lo estoy tratando de restaurar.

cree una base de datos para cargar el backup en esta pero no me habilita la opcion de standby file para buscar el archivo .bak que tengo que cargar para restaurar el backup.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto lo estoy realizando desde sql 2012

Comment: Allí no es donde seleccionas el archivo .bak. Revisa el [instructivo oficial](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/quickstart-backup-restore-database?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ssms#restore-a-backup)

Comment: ok, ahora me marca este error 
Restore of database 'DHS_MAIN' failed.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The operating system returned the error '5(Access is denied.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.COMPAC2\MSSQL\DATA\DHS_MAIN.mdf'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Comment: Es un error de permisos del sistema operativo. El usuario con el que corre el motor de base de datos tiene que tener permiso a la carpeta donde se guarden los archivos de la base de datos. Creo que fue en el 2012 que el instalador comenzó a crear un usuario con el que corre el motor y ese, por defecto, tiene los permisos a las carpetas (antes corría con el usuario del sistema, lo cual era un agujero tremendo de seguridad).  Si has cambiado algo de lo que queda por defecto, ya queda en tí verificar que tenga bien esos permisos.